# How to add bibliographic data to a Google Scholar article?

Tags: publications, citations, google-scholar, bibliometrics

A recent article of mine has just been successfully crawled by the Google Scholar robots; however, since the article is quite large (>40 MB), only the abstract and some basic journal metadata was extracted, and not the article's PDF itself. This has meant that none of the article's bibliographic information has been processed (and, as such, none of the articles cited by my article have had those citations recorded within Scholar).

Is there anything I can do to attach that missing bibliographic data to the article on Scholar manually? Would it help for me to upload the article (or its bibliography) somewhere else entirely and wait for Scholar to crawl that? I notice that some other services (such as ResearchGate) have successfully extracted the article's bibliography - will that make any difference?

Ultimately, what I'm asking is: is there anything I can do to make it possible/easier for the Scholar robots to extract the citation data correctly from this paper?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On your Google Scholar profile page, you have two 'tools'

- the `+` to add article (preselected and manually)
- the edit option when you click on one of your articles.

> Is there anything I can do to attach that missing bibliographic data to the article on Scholar manually?

Click on the article, select edit, input missing bibliographic entries.
*NB: GS is missing key metadata fields. You can input the minimum to make your article citable/searchable!*
Wonder why DOI is not available!!

> PDF

Under "*Public Access*", you might be able to upload a copy of your article (if it's open access or has a mandate).
I must acknowledge this doesn't work well at times.

> Would it help for me to upload the article (or its bibliography) somewhere else entirely and wait for Scholar to crawl that?

It should help. Ensure, it's 'available'. Upload to well known repository (subject to articles right).
You may also want to take a look at [indexing of websites with scholarly articles in Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html)